# Water Freezing Quandary

Tags: hydrology

Good Day All,

I have quandary that I am unable to find an answer for.

I live in Ontario, Canada.  Then home I reside on is directly on a lakefront.  It makes for beautiful views and wonderful times in the summer with the kids.  In the winter time (currently January) it usually makes for wonderful ice skating and Funtime opportunities.

Here is my current issue/quandary.

The entire lake is frozen.  There are fishing huts setup, snowmobiles and ATV's are zooming by. Up until a week ago all the ice on our shoreline was frozen more than 8" thick.  Now, currently, all the other properties ice is solid... except mine.  It appears that directly in front of our concrete dock/shoreline, we have water in a liquid state.  The neighbours are skating on their rinks on either side of us...

Heres some geography for your own musings...  We reside on the Mississipi Lake just west of Ottawa, Ontario.  We've had cold and warm temperatures with some melting and rain in the past two weeks.  Again, that's the whole area, so all the ice went through the same treatment as everywhere else here.  Yet, directly in front of our home, it has thawed and is no longer freezing...

Comment: Is there a stream flowing or pipe discharging into the lake on your property?

Comment: is there any thing shading the water like a tree or a building,

Comment: In Minnesota we used to have to watch out for springs causing thin ice spots on some lakes.

Comment: "usually" - How many years?

Comment: My first thought is what is inside your concrete shoreline? If it has steel reinforcement I would suspect it has a greater thermal conductivity and may be heating the ice, preventing it from freezing.